# Random InternalServerError in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We're keeping getting the following error randomly on random query in ElasticSearch.

```
{
\"status\":500,
\"displayName\":\"InternalServerError\",
\"message\":\"JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'ards': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@4103c9af; line: 1, column: 38]]\",
\"body\":{
         \"error\":\"JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'ards': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@4103c9af; line: 1, column: 38]]\",\"status\":500
         }
}
```

It even happen when we run a very simple query e.g.

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":9,
  "query":{
    "terms":{
      "id": [496161,496895,500119,544238,547116,547302,547364,633486,657141]
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, the same query without one of the ids passes without an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the same issue as in the link bellow, the cause is `you have indexed a first document with ... as a boolean`.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/reason-unrecognized-token-john-was-expecting-true-false-or-null/29700

You might want to check the actual mapping at `<host>:<port>/<index>/<type>/_mapping`.

Comment: sounds similar, but I'm not sure how avoid it next time, is there a way to find which field was indexed as boolean?

Comment: @Guy Korland You can set up the mapping explicitly ([Put Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)) and then disable dynamic field mapping : [Dynamic field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you should use a bool or select as null but you are inserting ards there
Search your queries for ards and replace it with a bool statement

Comment: it's very strange because it even happen randomly when we run a very simple query by id

Comment: have you checked elasticsearch log after happening of problem ? check your sharding config and status too @GuyKorland